# Insert markup before and after elements from NodeList

Tags: javascript

I got the following mark up:

```
<ul class="category-top-navigation__group--level-2">
    <li class="category-top-navigation__item--column-1">
    <li class="category-top-navigation__item--column-1">
    <li class="category-top-navigation__item--column-2">
    <li class="category-top-navigation__item--column-2">
</ul>
```

By using the following JavaScript selector:

`document.querySelectorAll('.category-top-navigation__group--level-2 .category-top-navigation__item--column-1');`

I can select a NodeList of all the `column-1` or `column-2` elements. Now what I wanna do is wrap the elements with `column-1` and `column-2` with a new element, perhaps a span so that the new markup would look like this.

```
<ul class="category-top-navigation__group--level-2">
    <span class="new-element-1">
        <li class="category-top-navigation__item--column-1">
        <li class="category-top-navigation__item--column-1">
    </span>
    <span class="new-element-2">
        <li class="category-top-navigation__item--column-2">
        <li class="category-top-navigation__item--column-2">
    </span>
</ul>
```

I was thinking to use insertAdjacentHTML afterend and beforebegin, however I am not quite sure how to get this working, or if that is the best approach to the task.

Comment: Will all the category-top-navigation__item--column-1 are next to each other?

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Yes they will always be next to each other.

Comment: I can only use vanilla JS for it.

Comment: That would be invalid HTML - you can not insert span at this level, LI must be children of a list.